# Python, mySQL with variables

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have the following quesry, where the variables are arrays...

```
c.execute("INSERT into userData values=(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
            t[i],k[0],k[1],k[2],user[i],total)
```

This gives a syntax error.

I have also tried this:

```
a = "INSERT INTO userData VALUES ('"+t[i]+"','"+k[0]+"','"+k[1]+"','"+k[2]+"',
  '"+USER+"','"+total+"')"
c.execute(a)
conn.commit()
```

This does not update to the database, though there are no errors.
Note: `c` - cursor, `conn` - connection.

Comment: What kind of syntax error do you get exactly?

Comment: Try this `c.excecute("INSERT into userData values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",( t[i],k[0],k[1],k[2],user[i],total))` it is beacause the second parameter to execute model is tuple of arguments and there is no need for `=`

Answer (score 1):

[`cursor.execute()`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#cursor-objects) expects the query parameters as a tuple. Try this:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO userData VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
               (t[i], k[0], k[1], k[2], user[i], total))
```

Don't use `+` or the like for constructing SQL queries, as this can lead to SQL-injection vulnerabilities in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table(col1,col2,...)VALUES(val1,val2,...)
```